# Django - Python - URL didn't match any of these

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

When I write code like this without `.html` in the end of `about/`:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('categories/', views.categories, name='categories'),
    path('docAdd/', views.docAdd, name='docAdd')
]
```

I get errors when click on about in the navbar of my webpage, error in that case is :

> " The current path, about.html, didn't match any of these." But when I change about/ to about.html/ then I can click on about in navbar and page opens, but when I switch from about to contact in navbar I get error like: "The current path, about.html/contact.html, didn't match any of these."

This is the code with `.html` suffix:

```
from django.urls import path
    from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, name='index'),
        path('about.html/', views.about, name='about'),
        path('contact.html/', views.contact, name='contact'),
        path('categories.html/', views.categories, name='categories'),
        path('docAdd.html/', views.docAdd, name='docAdd')
    ]
```

views.py code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . models import Document

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html')

def contact(request):
    return render(request, 'contact.html')

def categories(request):
    return render(request, 'categories.html')

def docAdd(request):
    return render(request, 'docAdd.html')
```

This is the error when I click on about in navbar two times, when I have `.html`suffix with about/ in urls.py:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/about.html/about.html
Using the URLconf defined in thesisProject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='index']
about.html/ [name='about']
contact.html/ [name='contact']
categories.html/ [name='categories']
docAdd.html/ [name='docAdd']
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, about.html/about.html, didn't match any of these.
```

This is the error when I click on about in navbar one time, when I have dont have `.html`suffix with about/ in urls.py:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/about.html/about.html
Using the URLconf defined in thesisProject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='index']
about.html/ [name='about']
contact.html/ [name='contact']
categories.html/ [name='categories']
docAdd.html/ [name='docAdd']
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, about.html, didn't match any of these.
```

Code for navbar in index.html:

```
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="ftco-nav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active"><a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="about.html" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="categories.html" class="nav-link">Categories</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="docAdd.html" class="nav-link">Add New Documents</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item cta"><a href="contact.html" class="nav-link"><span>Get in touch</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- END nav -->
```

I can't seem to solve this, please help.

Comment: Can you show the template code used to create the navbar?

Comment: @FiddleStix I added that as well please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that in the html u probably haven’t put a slash before the nav It should be like this

```
 <a href=“/about/”>
```

This will go to about.html rather than add /about.html to the end of the url.

So on the nav bar it should be:

```
<li class="nav-item"><a href="/about/" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
```

change your nav bar to this:

```
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="ftco-nav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active"><a href="/index/" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="/about/" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="/categories/" class="nav-link">Categories</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="/docAdd/" class="nav-link">Add New Documents</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item cta"><a href="/contact/" class="nav-link"><span>Get in touch</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

urls.py should look like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from main import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('categories/', views.categories, name='categories'),
    path('docAdd/', views.docAdd, name='docAdd')
]
```

I hope this helps please comment if you don’t understand what I have put.

Comment: this doesn' help

Comment: The problem doesn’t seem to be with django but instead the html links

Comment: @Sultan take the .html out of the urls so instead of /about.html it should be /about

Comment: please could you upload your project to github and send reply with a link to it so i can add the fix to your problem

Comment: I don't have `.html`suffix anymore, and problem is still there

Comment: please could you upload the whole html file and settings file

Comment: Yes I am uploading to github, give me some time

Comment: Thanks send me the link once complete :)

Comment: sorry it took me sometime to understand github uploading and solving the push issues, here is the link to the project: https://github.com/awan58/django/tree/master/thesis

Comment: Ok please let me know when you have something

Comment: Okay I belive i have fixed it going to upload it and send you a link

Comment: here is the link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1R0iTJp7sg0RzVc58dkeSffxRDb7APm42?usp=sharing tell me if you have any troubles downloading

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's solved now, can you tell me where was the problem actually

Comment: It was to do with firstly in the html links you put for example on the about page /about.html/ and in django you dont need to put the .html on the url because the url in the urls folder knows the name of the template because you have told it when you refrance the views.py file. btw the website looks really good and also remeber to tick the answered box on stack overflow so people know you've go the answer :)

Comment: Thanks @Zack Turner for the help, I changed that I already but it was not working then. Anyways problem is solved. Thanks for the website appreciation.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should not include `.html` in your urls file.

And when you put your link in the `<a>` tag, you should use a django **url-reversion** [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url) like this:

```
{% url 'about' %}

<li class="nav-item"><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
```

Also ensure you have a templates file [setup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/#configuration) in your app directory.

Comment: Did you mean this:           `<li class="nav-item"><a href="{% url 'about' %}" class="nav-link">About</a></li>`
tried what you said, and got this error:

`Using the URLconf defined in thesisProject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='index']
about/ [name='about']
contact/ [name='contact']
categories/ [name='categories']
docAdd/ [name='docAdd']
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, about.html/, didn't match any of these.`

Comment: Ok, you probably haven't set up the urls or views when defining the name of the html file that should be given for that url. For example, if your code is calling for 'about.html/' django isn't able to find that in its file paths, i can't see your file paths and so can't fully help, Try and add a / to the beginning of the link in the a tag for your navbar (just follow zack tuners post). https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/ https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/

Comment: I don't know where the problem is

Comment: here is the link to whole project: https://github.com/awan58/django/tree/master/thesis please see if you can help